# changing options of one select tag based on the input of another select tag

Tags: jquery, html, forms, html-select

I am trying to change the options of the second select tag based on the input from the first select tag.

```js
function selectMake() {
  $("#year").change(function() {
    var y = $(this).val();
    if (y == "2018") {
      $("#make").html("<option value='make1'>make 1</option><option value='make2'>make 2</option>");
    } else if (y == "2017") {
      $("#make").html("<option value='make3'>make 3</option><option value='make4'>make 4</option>");
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="js-select2" id="year" name="year[]" oninput='selectMake()'>
  <option value="">Please chooses Year</option>
  <option>2018</option>
  <option>2017</option>
</select>
<div class="dropDownSelect2"></div>
</div>
</div>


<div class="wrap-input100 input100-select bg1">
  <span class="label-input100">Make *</span>
  <div>
    <select class="js-select2" id="make" name="make[]" oninput="selectModel()">
      <option value="">Please chooses Make</option>
    </select>
    <div class="dropDownSelect2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Neither am I getting the desired output nor am i getting any error.
is there something wrong with my code? i do not wish to use `document.ready()` since I have to call this function multiple times.

Comment: Wait, when you don't call `document.ready()`, it won't even get registered when the `select` is added to the DOM. You can even delegate the event to the static parent if it's dynamic.

Comment: Also `selectMake()` is not the same as `selectModel()`!

Comment: isn't it working fine ? test it.

Comment: Yep... Looks like it works fine on the question...

Comment: @PraveenKumar `selectModel()` is a different function

Comment: @GeorgeBailey it's not!!

Comment: @NEETHINNambiar Okay, in that case, Does it work on the snippet?

Comment: it works fine on the snippet

Comment: @NEETHINNambiar Try using `onchange` instead of `oninput`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine with Chrome and other latest browsers that support oninput. Only issue is that it's not working in IE 11 browser, to fix that you need to use onchange instead of oninput like below,

```
<select class="js-select2" id="year" name="year[]" onchange='selectMake()'>
  <option value="">Please chooses Year</option>
  <option>2018</option>
  <option>2017</option>
</select>
```

I've just verified in several other browsers, and they're working fine too

Comment: its working now.thank you!!!

Comment: but i had tried oninput some hours ago and it was working fine.

Comment: Did you try in the same browser with same configuration ?

Comment: yes. infact the code i gave you was the edited version of  the code that was working on oninput

Comment: I just verified your original code with IE browser and it didn't work. It worked only with onchange